# How to use getChild in robotium?

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have `LinearLayout` with different child elements like `LinearLayouts` and `FrameLayouts` in hierarchy viewer. How can I click on their elements by `solo.clickOnView`? I cant find any algorithm to get these Views, is it possible with `getChild()` method?

Comment: Imho, layout is something what shouldn't be clickable.

Comment: I mean their elements)

Answer (score 0):

You can access View by R.id:

```
solo.getView(int id);
solo.getView(String id);
```

You can access view by index:

```
solo.getView(Class<T> viewClass, int index);
```

Finally you can use whatever you want from android API, including getChild

Comment: I have only th .apk file, so I can't use R.id. I have several layouts with elements, that have the same index, so I can't get them by direct getView() method, as I understand.

Comment: you can use R.id - solo.getView(String id);
show your hierarchy of views, then we can think how to access specified views

Comment: @user1835337 You could use Hierarchyviewer with a compatible device or via emulator then run the app. Load up the layout and click the view you want to use to know its ID via its properties.

Comment: [I created new question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879103/how-to-use-r-id-in-robotium-if-i-have-only-the-apk-file/17905193?noredirect=1#17905193)
I'm trying to use `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView("cn.wps.moffice_eng.R.id.writer_edittoolbar_saveBtn"));` and it can't find any View, where is the problem?